# why completion does not work for all aliases?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, alias

In my `.bash_aliases` file I have couple of aliases, like --

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias emx='emacs'
alias em='emacs -nw'
alias gv='gvim'
alias v='vi'
alias ev='evince'
```

when I use them and press [tab] for auto completion, they work --

```
:~/$ emx main-0 [press tab]
main-04.cpp       main-05.cpp       main-06.cpp       main-06-test.cpp
```

or

```
:~/$ em main-0 [press tab]
main-04.cpp       main-05.cpp       main-06.cpp       main-06-test.cpp
```

both for `emx` and `em` they work (also `ev` works), but when I try to use `gv` or `v`, it does not --

```
:~/$ gv main-0 [press tab]
<nothing happens>
```

why ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it's a point of confusion, `expand_aliases` determines if aliases are checked when processing commands, it's a different thing altogether to *completion*.

It sounds like you have per-command completion set up, check the output of `complete` (no arguments). `gv` is conventionally the *ghostview* command, so it's possible that `gv` completion is only searching for PS/EPS/PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Bash auto-completion simply reads what you put in the command line without resolving aliases. If you put the command name, then it reads the command name. If you put an alias, then it reads the alias. So as far as completion is concerned, `gv` has nothing to do with `gvim` in your case. In fact, `gv` is a name defined in [bash-completion](https://github.com/brechtm/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L1781) script as:

```
_install_xspec '!*.@(@(?(e)ps|?(E)PS|pdf|PDF)?(.gz|.GZ|.bz2|.BZ2|.Z))' gv ggv kghostview
complete -F _filedir_xspec gv
```

So basically it only matches uncompressed and compressed ps and pdf files.

AFAIK you have 2 ways to deal with this:

1. Set alias completion for `gv` to a different function. For example, `_longopt` works in your case:

   ```
   complete -F _longopt gv
   ```
2. Write a generic alias completion function and use it on `gv`. Luckily someone has done this for you: https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias